# How to Group and Order by in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, group-by

How can I group by fields and Order by DESC in cakephp?

```
$this->set('messages', $this->Message->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Message.receiver_id'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')),'group' => array('Message.user_id'),'order' => array('max(Message.created) ASC'))));
```

Comment: Use group and order param in cakephp query

Comment: You code is not working for order because group by and order by both not work for a single table. to make order by fictional you need to make 2 query main and sub query. sub query first order by the records and main query group by ordered record.

Answer (score 2):

Records are fetched in cakePhp depend on a model is

```
$records = $this->Model->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(conditons),
            'fields' => array(fieldlist),
            'group' => array('Model.column'),
            'order' => array('Model.column', 'Model.column2 DESC')
        ));
```

From your code, you can write as

```
$data = $this->Message->find('all', array(
               'conditions' => array( 'Message.receiver_id'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')),
               'group' => array('Message.user_id'),
               'order' => array('max(Message.created) ASC')
               ));

$this->set('messages', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$records = $this->Model->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(conditons),
            'recursive' => -1,
            'fields' => array(fieldlist),
            'group' => array('Model.column'),
                    'order' => array('Model.column', 'Model.column2 DESC')
        ));
```

If you want to order by latest Message inserted then instead of sort by `created` use sort by `id` like this `Model.id DESC'`

Comment: Not working as expected. It doesn't order the results